# Case Creation-Email Notification Not Using Org wide address

Tags: org-wide-email

We are wanting to send emails to customers with the Org Wide Address which is set up to use all profiles and as default. When sending a case creation email notification the email sent is from whoever created the case and not the org. I've searched and searched with no luck of finding a solution or an answer stating that this is just the salesforce way. Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `case creation email notification` - is this an auto-response rule custom email or what?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to hide the "Send notification email to contact" checkbox from layout during case creation and rather have an flow (after insert) to send the email notification to contact. When you do it via flow, you will have an option to chose From address.

you could toggle the email notification checkbox using layout properties of case layout.
[image: case layout]